# Save XML file on my machine with XMLDom object save()

Tags: javascript, xml

I'm not able to save to the xml file on my machine.
I have noticed that node value is changed temprorily but not permanent in xml file.

P.S : This is only a simple HTML file with javascript

It is giving me an error "Permission Denied"

```
function viewBookDetails() {
var xmlDoc = xmlLoader("cart.xml");

//var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("dogHouse")[0];
var x = xmlDoc.documentElement;

var newel = xmlDoc.createElement("essy");
x.appendChild(newel);

alert(x.xml);
xmlDoc.save("cart.xml");
}
```

is it not possible to save xml file on my machine?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

In general, browser JavaScript has no I/O API and cannot read or write to the client filesystem since that could be a security loophole. I haven't seen or used the `save()` method before but it looks like it's [an IE specific extension to the XML DOM](http://www.devguru.com/technologies/xmldom/quickref/document_save.html). If you *must* use it, [this thread might provide the solution](http://forums.devshed.com/javascript-development-115/save-xml-file-using-javascript-573230.html), the answer that worked for the OP there suggested:

> I haven't proofed your code but here is something you might want to try. I am taking a shot in the dark that you are using this on a Windows OS since you are using IE and from the sound of the error. Just take your html file that you have and rename it the whatever.hta and it will then be able to write to the xml file and save.

Also, the [documentation for the method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753769%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says the following for when the argument is a string (as in your code snippet):

> **String**
>   Specifies the file name. This must be a file name rather than a URL. The file is created, if necessary, and the contents are replaced entirely with the contents of the saved document. This mode is not intended for use from a secure client, such as Microsoft Internet Explorer.

---

From the forum posts (links below) that deal with the same issue, I gleaned the following:

- This is an IE specific extension and so will only work in IE
- There are obviously security restrictions in place so you shouldn't be able to do this 'out of the box'
- One workaround that crops up often is to rename the file extension to `.hta` (Hypertext Application) instead of `.html`
- I'm not sure but there might also be some workarounds by changing the permissions for the security zones your application runs in

**References:**

- http://www.codingforums.com/showthread.php?t=25048
- http://p2p.wrox.com/xml/4053-error-using-xml-save-method.html
- http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/javascript-dhtml-ajax/threads/204995

Comment: I tried the .hta extension and it worked but not the way i wanted it to work. The .hta deflates the purpose of the project that i'm working on. that you very much for helping out